# How to Google mock function that returns a std::function?

Tags: c++, lambda, mocking, googlemock

I have some code that uses an interface with a method that returns a std::function.  In testing my code I need to mock that interface in order to verify the code handles a variety of values the interface may provide.

**Interface to be mocked:**

```
class Foo_ifc {
public:
   virtual ~Foo_ifc(){};
   virtual std::function<int(std::string)> get_func(std::string str) = 0;
};

class Foo_mock : public Foo_ifc {
public:
   MOCK_METHOD1(get_func, std::function<int(std::string)>(std::string str));
};
```

**Code using the interface:**

```
std::shared_ptr<Foo_ifc> my_ifc = std::make_shared<Foo_mock>();

int do_something(std::string thing_to_do)
{
   // Use Foo_ifc to find the function to call for the given string and call it
   return my_ifc->get_func(thing_to_do)();
}
```

**Test of the code using the interface:**

```
TEST(get_func_test, find_known_functions)
{
   // Setup the data I want my mocked interface to return

   // It needs to return a function that takes a string and returns
   // an integer.
   int tmp = 5;
   std::function<int(std::string)> f = [&tmp](std::string const &ref) { return tmp; };

   // Make Foo_mock return our new function for all calls to get_func()
   EXPECT_CALL(*Foo_mock, get_func(_)).WillRepeatedly(Return(f));

   // Our code under test should now return '5' when calling 'do_something'
   // no matter what string is passed to 'do_something'
   EXPECT_EQ(do_something("fubar"), 5);
}
```

Google mock is telling me:

> GMOCK WARNING:
>   Uninteresting mock function call - returning default value.
>   Function call:
>     get_func("fubar")
>     Returns: 0

This makes me believe I am not setting up my EXPECT_CALL such that it returns my function **f** properly.

What am I screwing up?

Comment: `return my_ifc->get_func(thing_to_do)()` should probably be `return my_ifc->get_func(thing_to_do)("any string")`.

Comment: should it be `EXPECT_CALL(*my_ifc, get_func(_)).WillRepeatedly(Return(f));` ?

Comment: You are correct.  I was too hasty in authoring my TEST case and did a poor job translating my real code to generic code capable of being shared publicly.  My TEST case needs to have the EXPECT_CALL operate on `my_ifc`.